# Format date value in MongoDB shell FIND script

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

Here is my **Mongo Shell Script**

```
db.MyCollection.find({ "ProjectID" : 999 } }, { 
    "_id" : 0, 
    "DueDate" : 1
     }).sort({ "CreatedDate" : -1 })
```

**Result**

```
{
   "DueDate" : ISODate("2016-02-20T08:00:00.000Z")
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{ 
 "DueDate" : "2016-02-20 08:00 AM"
}
```

Tried following this [article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          yearMonthDay: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$DueDate" } },
          time: { $dateToString: { format: "%H:%M:%S:%L", date: "$DueDate" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

That give following **null** result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578e3bb48c305af06d30147e"),
    "yearMonthDay" : null,
    "time" : null
}
```

How can I get this work, I also would like to add other fields to the projection with out any formatting for those

Comment: Very strange, I have tried your aggregate query and it returns `{ "_id" : ..., "yearMonthDay" : "2016-02-20", "time" : "08:00:00:000" }` for the document that you provided. `null` values are not present in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation pipeline you are running has the wrong **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** format. You need to run this pipeline to get the right result:

```
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "ProjectID" : 999 } },
    { "$sort": { "CreatedDate": -1 } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "DueDate": {
                "$dateToString": { 
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M", 
                    "date": "$DueDate"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

which happens to be the date formatted version of the mongo shell query:

```
db.MyCollection.find(
    { "ProjectID" : 999 } 
    { "_id" : 0, "DueDate" : 1 }
}).sort({ "CreatedDate" : -1 })
```

Comment: How can I convert this to Local time ISO date ISODate("2016-10-08T17:00:00.000Z") returns as "2016-10-08 17-00" which is actually  Saturday, October 08, 2016 22:30:00